# C# switching windows in .net

Tags: c#, .net, process, dllimport

Hi I'm trying to switch windows to other programs that are running (even if minimized) using C#.

I'm wondering why this won't work.

Error message: 
Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Diagnostics.Process' to 'System.IntPtr'

By the time it hits the loop I would think that the proc variable would refer to the appropriate window handler.  Is this not true?
I really appreciate the help.

```
//declarations
using system.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
//more

//namespace here

//class here

//initialize method

//related .dll import
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

String ProcWindow = "itunes";
//function which calls switchWindow() is here but not important

//now we have switch window.
private void switchWindow()
        {
            Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcWindow);
            foreach (Process proc in procs)
            {
                //switch to process by name
                SwitchToThisWindow(proc);

            }
        }
```

For future readers:
I got to this point in my code from another question.
[Correct way (in .NET) to switch the focus to another application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315561/correct-way-in-net-to-switch-the-focus-to-another-application)

Comment: The process object isn't the process handle (which an intptr).   Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276629/c-sharp-get-running-process-given-process-handle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**SwitchToThisWindow** is expecting a **handle** to the window that you want to switch to in that process.

Try

```
SwitchToThisWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
```

Comment: Awesome, so it has properties I can access.

Comment: What else can you get by doing proc.?
Is there a good article on it?

Comment: Absolutely, MSDN will always be your best resource: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I believe what you want is:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern void SwitchToThisWindow(IntPtr hWnd, bool turnon);

String ProcWindow = "itunes";
//function which calls switchWindow() is here but not important

//now we have switch window.
private void switchWindow()
{
  Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName(ProcWindow);
  foreach (Process proc in procs)
  {
     //switch to process by name
     SwitchToThisWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle, false);

  }
}
```

SwitchToThisWindow expects an IntPtr that is a handle to a window, not a process which is what you were trying to pass in.

Also note that your pinvoke signature for SwitchToThisWindow appeared to be incorrect, you were missing the bool parameter.

Comment: Boolean parameter should be false. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633553%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Noted, 
I have updated it.  Thanks for helping me improve my code.  I appreciate the article too, so I can understand why it should be false.

Comment: Another quick related question.  How can I detect through the api if the window is open?  If it is, then I will call this function